# Handle clicks and ajax calls in a checksession function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have set up an AJAX function that helps me logout the user after 15 mins of inactivity - and I mean here without page refresh, and it's working well.

However the problem is the user can be still working (clicking on objects, sending AJAX calls, etc.) without refreshing page. However he will be disconnected within those 15 mins.

How can I handle the clicks and AJAX calls in a check session system?

```js
function xhrSessionIsExpired(controller) {      
  $.ajax({
    url: controller + "/xhrSessionIsExpired",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(json) {
      if (json == 'alive') {
        console.log('alive');
      }
      if (json == 'expired') {
        console.log('expired');
        document.location.href = baseUrl + 'index/timeout';
      }
      if (json == 'out') {
        console.log('out');
        document.location.href = baseUrl + 'index/disconnected';
      }
      setTimeout ("xhrSessionIsExpired('" + controller + "');", 15000);
    },
    complete: function() {},
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      showAjaxMessage (7041, "error",  allMsg["allMsgAjax"]["error"]);
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}
```

```php
function xhrSessionIsExpired() 
{
  if (Session::get('loggedIn') == true)
  {
    if (Session::expired() == false)
    {
      $res = 'alive';
    }
    else 
    {
      $res = 'expired';
      $return = Session::destroy();
    }
  }
  else 
  {
    $res = 'out';
  }
  echo json_encode($res);
}
```

Comment: Why you does not just set some variable in js, after 15 mins that is user expired and check it before do any ajax request?

Comment: ok ! Now during the 15mns how can i know the session is still active ? Do i have to update the variable anytime he makes a click or what ?

Comment: I thought that you did some of activity listener wchich monitors user clicks, mouse movement, keypress etc. `setTimeout` for 15 mins and stop it when action appear and restart after some time. When timeout fire you set indicator variable to true and logout user with ajax also display some alert that session expired